# Hibernate: getting data from two linked tables using Ctriteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

How can I get data from two linked tables (one-to-many: one User and many Results) by value '**ispassed**' (boolean) using Ctriteria API? [image]

```
    private List<?> winners;    

    try {           
            SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            Session hSession = factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = null;

                try {

                    tx = hSession.beginTransaction();
                    winners = hSession.createSQLQuery("select * from usertable u, resulttable r where u.id = r.id where r.ispassed = true").list();
                    tx.commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (tx != null)
                        tx.rollback();
                } finally {
                    hSession.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(winners.size()); // an exception
```

Comment: as you wrote winners.size()  may be throwing an exception because List<?> winners  could be null

Comment: that's true, but why is it?

Comment: because your Session.createSQLQuery("select * from usertable u, resulttable r where u.id = r.id where r.ispassed = true").list(); is returning null list

Comment: that's clear I mean is something wrong with query?

Comment: yes you are using  r.ispassed = true  instate of  r.ispassed = 1 while using  session.createSQLQuery ,it basically creates native sql query.

Comment: it seems I used everything: createSQLQuery and createQuery with 1 and true...

Comment: what i am suggesting here is as  mention in my answer use createQuery and use r.ispassed = true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76019/discussion-between-dev-and-andy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HQL:

```
from usertable u, resulttable r where u.id = r.id
where r.ispassed = 1
```

This will return a list of [User,result] arrays.

Change you code like:

```
private List<?> winners;    

try {           
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session hSession = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

        try {

            tx = hSession.beginTransaction();
            winners = hSession.createSQLQuery("from usertable u, resulttable r where u.id = r.id and r.ispassed = true").list();
            tx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
        } finally {
            hSession.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(winners.size());
```

**EDIT:**

```
CriteriaBuilder b = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> c = b.createTupleQuery();
Root<EntityX> entityXRoot= c.from(EntityX.class);
Root<EntityY> entityYRoot = c.from(EntityY.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
//Here you need to add the predicates you need

List<Predicate> andPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
andPredicates.add(b.equal(entityXRoot.get("id"), entityYRoot.get("id")));
andPredicates.add(b.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));

c.multiselect(entityXRoot, entityYRoot);
c.where(andPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

TypedQuery<Tuple> q = em.createQuery(criteria);

List<Tuple> result = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the same using Ctriteria API?

Comment: @Andy:- Updating my answer. Please wait!

Comment: @Andy:- Please check now!

Comment: thanks, but I'll probably stay with hql coz criteria example seems much more complicated.

Comment: list is null after `List <?> list = hSession.createSQLQuery("select * from usertable u, resulttable r where u.id = r.id where r.ispassed = 1").list();`

Comment: @Andy:- Did you checked the ispassed value is true or 1 in your table?

Comment: the ispassed value is 1 in resulttable and `hibernate.cfg.xml` also contains 
`<property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0</property>`

Comment: @Andy:- Did you tried to check it with `r.ispassed = true` ?

Comment: @Andy:- Can you paste your relevant code which you are executing?

Comment: Hello @RahulTripathi with native sql query if i run you query with mysql terminal it gives me error it should be 
select * from usertable u, resulttable r where u.id = r.id
and r.ispassed = 1

Comment: MySQL <> HQL. The above query was used for HQL syntax! Also to add `*` is meaningless in HQL. In MYSQL terminal the query you pasted will work but not in HQL

Comment: @RahulTripathi edit your answer to make it solution. change the last "where" to "and"

Answer (score 1):

You can create your entity class like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RESULTS")
public class Results implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User userId;

    @Column(name = "IS_PASSED")
    private Boolean ispassed;

    other property
    ... getter() setter()
}

@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Results> resultsSet;

    other property
    ... getter() setter()
}
```

And in your hibernate.cfg.xml file if set below property

```
<property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0</property>
```

Execute below HQL query

```
String sql = "from User as user "
                + "inner join user.resultsSet"
                + "where resultsSet.ispassed= true";
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql);
        List<User> UserList = query.list();
```

above is how you can get List of User, now you need to Iterate User list and use getter method get all results.